# How to integrate moskito-java (monitoring-tool) into a grails application?

Tags: grails, groovy, monitoring, servlet-filters

I would like to use [moskito](http://www.moskito.org/) monitoring within my grails 2.3.9 application.
I already added the dependencies for moskito and the webui into BuildConfig.groovy

```
compile 'net.anotheria:moskito-core:2.4.2'
compile 'net.anotheria:moskito-aop:2.4.2'
runtime 'net.anotheria:moskito-webui:2.4.2'
runtime 'net.anotheria:moskito-web:2.4.2'
runtime 'net.anotheria:moskito-webui-jersey:2.4.2'
```

I also marked the classes i want to monitor with the `@Monitor` annotation.

Now i need to get access to the moskito-webui. I need to add a servlet filter to the web.xml of the grails application (regarding to the [documentation](https://confluence.opensource.anotheria.net/display/MSK/Embedding+Moskito-WebUI+Into+Your+Application)). I just installed the grails templates with `grails install-templates` and modified the web.xml file but i can't get access to the webui of moskito.

Does somebody know how to create an urlmapping or servlet filter for moskito webui within grails? How to integrate it correctly?

Answer (score 3):

if you upgrade to 2.5.0 you don't need an embedded webui, instead you can use a standalone tool called MoSKito Inspect (actually same as WebUI, nicer name). 
First add

```
moskito-inspect-remote
```

to your dependencies. This jar includes a web-fragment that starts a local listener on RMI port 9041 (port can be altered later).

Second: Download or build your own MoSKito Inspect (take tomcat7 and drop in http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=net/anotheria/moskito-inspect-standalone/2.5.0/moskito-inspect-standalone-2.5.0.war or build from github source).

Download link is:
http://www.moskito.org/download.html

Third: start your application and MoSKito Inspect. Enter in quickconnect localhost and port 9401. You should see your annotated classes now.

If you have further problems you can also use moskito mailing list: moskito-users@lists.anotheria.net

regards

Leon

Comment: Hi Leon, thanks for your fast answer! I integrated moskito as you said and annotated my project classes. After deploying moskito-inspect and connecting to localhost:9041 i get the following exception: Cannot connect to localhost@localhost:9041, due: Can not resolve manually set reference. Server at localhost, port: 9041 is down or not properly configured...

Comment: check out this link: http://blog.anotheria.net/msk/the-complete-moskito-integration-guide-step-1/ maybe you forgot a step or two.
I assume your problem is that you didn't provide a catalina.sh property (and I didn't mentioned it either):

export JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -DlocalRmiRegistryPort=9401"

Comment: Hi Leon, what's about security? Do i have to secure the rmi port by myself or is there any security feature integrated?

Comment: Hi whitenexx, sorry, I somehow didn't see your comment previously. There is currently no security in the rmi layer. The attacker would have to know that your are using MoSKito and which version, and also have access to your network infrastructure. But if you feel that it would be reasonable to add an additional security layer to the rmi communication, please open a ticket at http://jira.opensource.anotheria.net.